# proving a binary operation is well-defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

Theorem 4 of Landau's "Foundations of Analysis" defines sum of two numbers. He fixes one argument and prove it for the other and vice versa. I want to know why we can do this. I think the proper way   to prove the operation is well defined, is to show if $x=x'$ and $y=y'$ then $+ (x,y) = + (x',y')$. In other words you have to consider "$\forall x \forall y  $" together.

One other issue is that I cannot quite understand his uniquness proof based on defining $a_y , b_y$ either. Isn't he over complicate things in his proof? 
[here is how he does it.](https://books.google.com/books?id=DvIJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is using a technique called "currying". Let's say you have a function of two variables (say $x$ and $y$). We'll say the $x$'s live in set $A$, and the $y$'s live in set $B$, and the computed value lives in set $C$, like so:

$f:A \times B \to C$, and $z = f(x,y)$ (where $z$, of course, lives in $C$).

Now, we might want to deal with just "one variable at a time", so we'll make an "new function":

$g:A \to C^B$, that for every $x$, gives us a function $g_x$ that goes from $B \to C$. And we'll use $f$ to define the value of $g_x$ at every $y$:

$g_x(y) = f(x,y)$.

Here is an example, related to what you're reading.

Let $A = B = C = \Bbb Z$, our friends the integers. We have the "add two numbers" function:

$s(x,y) = x+y$.

Now let's fix $x$, say, $x = 4$. Our "new function" is the function takes $4$ to the function that takes $y \mapsto 4+y$ (in other words, it maps $4$ to the "add four function"). Note that we have:

$g_4(y) = 4 + y = s(4,y)$.

There's nothing special about $4$, we could do this for any integer $x$: map $x$ to the function: $g_x$ which adds $x$ to the input.

Then $s(x,y) = [g(x)](y) = g_x(y) = x + y$.

This lets us work "one variable at a time", first we deal with $x$, then we deal with $y$. However, it "conceptually denser" because we have "functions of functions", in order to feed the inputs in a single stream, instead of "in parallel".

One reason for doing this in developing the natural numbers, for example, is that it allows us to do "one induction at a time" instead of doing "double induction" or "an induction within an induction" where it might be hard to keep track of where you "are".

Comment: Could you please give a reference to the proof of currying?

Comment: it's a bit more involved than you might think-start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying